# LWUIT Symbol table

Tags: localization, lwuit, symbol-table

I'm facing a problem with symboltabel. I'm using Persian and English languages in my [LWUIT](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lwuit-intro-138622.html) application with the help of Localization.

Now my problem is that when I press * button of any mobile device, some of the Symbol Tabel chars are getting translated to Persian characters and some remain same.

How can I fix this problem?